# Using Mod_redirect QUERY_STRING to block URLS

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write rewrite rules to block URLs with some particular pattern. The requests are as follows as seen in Apache log.

```
"GET /mysecure/Docs?cb=20414624755 HTTP/1.1" 200 881107 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"
```

I want to block all requests with `QUERY_STRING cb=20414624755` .

For this I have written the following rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^cb=20414624755$" [nocase]
RewriteRule ^\/mysecure\/Docs$ - [forbidden,last]
```

But the requests are not getting blocked.In apache access log file , I can see `200 Response code` for the requests with these patterns.

Please suggest.

Comment: To clarify, are these directives directly in the server config (or virtual host)?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^cb=20414624755$" [nocase]
> RewriteRule ^\/mysecure\/Docs$ - [forbidden,last]
> ```

These directives will match the stated request if they are used directly in the server config (or virtual host). However, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* will not match the URL-path if used in a *directory* or `.htaccess` context (which I can only assume is where they are being used in this instance?).

When used in a `.htaccess` file, the directory-prefix (of where the `.htaccess` file is located) is first removed from the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. The directory-prefix always ends with a slash, so the matched URL-path never starts with a slash.

To make this work in both a server and directory context you can make the preceding slash optional:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cb=20414624755$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?mysecure/Docs$ - [F]
```

There is no need to escape the slashes in the regex. I've used the shorthand *flags*, since they are far more common in usage. The `L` (`last`) is not required when used with `F` (`forbidden`) - it is implied. The quotes around the *CondPattern* are not required here.